# How to decode a polyline and draw it on a google map using "@react-google-maps/api"

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, polyline, google-polyline, react-google-maps-api

I'm trying to use the `@react-google-maps/api` library to render a Google map on a react component and draw a polyline on the map, however, the polyline data that comes from the backend is encoded like this ...

```
@iBwCyC}FiA_BkAqBcDuD_GwF}KcJkTwQwVuSiPeNyJeIaEaEsZeWmMmKgg@cb@mToQqIqG_EiB}Aa@uCYyBI_CHeBVoI|B_Cn@qCb@eF^mAFcZEuEEqCM}BYqCaAuC_BcBqA}@iA{AwBaAmBgB}FyIaC{@mA_FsKuDgIwC_He@eA}JuTgS{c@yTcf@yLyVePm\\
```

How to decode that poline and draw it on the map using `@react-google-maps/api`?

Comment: What about https://github.com/googlemaps/js-polyline-codec ?

Comment: @AnatoliiSuhanov, thank you for your answer, but I was wondering if there is a decoder in `@react-google-maps/api` package, because their docs website is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@react-google-maps/api doesn't have a decoder, but you can use this [package](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-polyline-codec)

```
import { decode, encode } from "@googlemaps/polyline-codec";

const encoded = "_p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@";
console.log(decode(encoded, 5));
// [
//   [38.5, -120.2],
//   [40.7, -120.95],
//   [43.252, -126.453],
// ]
```