# How do I display the result of Google's computeRoute API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I am using the computeRoute post method provided by Google's Routes API. The method returns a JSON file with the following data :

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "distanceMeters": 99537,
            "duration": "6977s",
            "polyline": {
                "encodedPolyline": "y`hbEqrfzEw@HYJUTS\\Qf@Kl@EHETQVQJe@FQJyDJuBNc@?{@JwAf@qAb@m@NkBZs@D_A@cBGm@Io@OqBw@i@UkMqEcD}@oB]kBMeDGaBDkEf@cJdBsC|@q@^qAfAaApAe@bAk@vAu@hCuCbPgF`XwB|L_CvLgFvZ[tAQfBkBpK{AtE}AtC}B~BmDzBoDrBs@d@{FdDsErCo@TuAT}A@sCOmLkC{DcAoCo@{E{@yD_@cBIuCAa@BSDsAJyB\\qA\\{CzAmAr@mAbAgBpBwA|Bc@x@y@tByAfF}B~IuAtGe@|CuA|FkAnF{BrJ{AlH}@rFwDbVm@~B_A`C_AjBkAjB_AfA_Ax@y@b@oAj@_ARgAJu@BYDoA@sJW}CDyGVoJn@qD\\_H~@}CRwCDqEGeB@wDPiF^_E\\_GZeABuAAqCSoB]sBi@qAg@i@WeCaB}AwAsLyLwKgL_FgEe@e@e@w@gBeBaBmAyAs@_AY}@QgBWwAEqAAaKTy@?cAGoC]wBk@}@_@kAu@}BaBcA{@m@s@m@{@_A_BaA{B{@aCwB_HaBuF{CmJ{EgPm@mBg@wAo@{AqAcCmBqCc@i@wBoBwCwBwJeGqPcJwBw@yA[iAK_AA}@BoANcB`@eBr@qAt@{@r@sEdFo@v@gAlBo@`Bc@|A[bBmAhK[tAs@|AgAvAe@`@q@d@{@`@mAb@}QvCiCXsHlAmEl@}Cn@eGdA{C^uCl@wAh@]PiAbASV{@pAc@dAo@dCM|@KfB?fADfAHv@b@fDTfCAlCM|A]|Ai@tA{@rA[`@yBxBkAdAu@t@aClCsAfBu@nAi@|AOj@Q`AMfAEbAApADvBR`Bb@|AZbAjN~YjBdEnErJ|@pBbEtIdOv[~CdH`ArBr@jCNjA@tAEl@UrA[x@O\\w@bAy@h@a@Ny@NqA@qCUcSkHcB_@wB_@iBSyBQwISsCKyAS{Ag@qDcBeA]q@OuAOcQDcHCmAFwAXwAZyDhAmAXsARyYbDqAH_D@wAGqC_@_OiDoG}AwCm@mHiBoCm@iEgAy@Mm@CkABw@Jw@Py@Xu@^uAlA_AjAaA`C]lBgBxOSbB]hBs@xBa@~@o@jAaAtAuApAk@j@mAt@o@ZuAf@_ATeBVu@HkBAiBKm@KwDcAwKeDkBc@qEg@mBCgBDkBPeC\\oBd@mD|A{Ax@{AfAmDrCaBjAy@`@u@Xm@Py@LyBHeAEsASuGyAgNqDeQaEu@W[OoAw@{@y@i@m@kAmBo@}AwDuNi@mAm@y@m@o@cAo@eAa@wAS_A?cAJw@Tc@Rm@`@wCvCk@r@gFfFqMdM}@t@u@\\}@X[F}@Du@Aw@O}@Y{@i@iAeAwK_LmAuAkAiBa@y@o@aB_BkFgBgFgAuBmA}AkB{Bm@iAe@qA_@gBS{BAcA@i@h@aJ?uAMcBOw@W{@o@uA[g@g@k@eA{@_Aa@cAW}@K{MaAgFc@oJo@eFc@mB_@mA_@gCeA}ByA}BoBuBiCiBuCqMyTyAqBgAiAk@_@{@c@aAa@kB_@oAG{@BiAH{AT_Gp@kDVgACeASk@Mu@a@YQq@o@w@iAWi@k@mB{AyGeA_EeDcNiAcFKmACeABoAdBmRPaBF{@?}AAk@KcBU{AOu@]s@yAsBq@q@eAy@aCkAkA[gDe@{JuA_B_@sAc@oBaAwBoA}AoAoAiACSaBiCkAwBm@m@WIs@EmIToJnC}AX_GHwAHeB\\g@N{Al@wAv@oChBwEbDaB`A{B`AeDbA{A\\aBTcW|AeALwHjBqFlAeBl@aDbBiA`@cAVoQpDs@F{AEeEo@q@EwAHeARyAf@mBn@a@JqAH_BA}@M}@WgAe@oIuEeB}@aDzFqBAmAGc@Ky@]_B{@{CgAcDyAmA_@[?S[}AcB{@q@m@WqAUi@CgBJk@Hq@T_@TiEdDa@Zo@t@kAzAc@`@QLs@?aBWcCo@iAMiACcADP~B@lBGhCCn@SfBe@tCc@zAcApCq@lAmAfBqAvAqBbBwA`AoAl@WR}Bl@gC^oMpA}@PgAj@_AhAw@xAW~@Kn@CzANbBvB~P`@hDJjAAtCINo@vFk@`BMTOJc@n@s@z@oEzEAP_E`E]f@Wl@Or@MpAAxAVvPF`GG~AKl@Up@i@fA]`@u@n@mCnAoPtH}Ax@qBzAyAzAkB|B}@zA_Utd@_@x@Ut@YfBMlC?tARpBvBzJRlAJnBRjMHtANbAb@vAlCrGVt@Rz@Nx@NrADjAA|AIvBUbDC~A@|AFhAH|@\\xBVlAn@tBx@hBzAxC`BvC~AxCLZdB|CjB~CdA~Ap@nA`@bAPj@Lt@tAhNj@hGpAhMHhA@`AIzAQjAg@~AcBdEk@`BcApCSt@EX?bADf@Tv@NZRZVTXP~Ar@j@^`@j@n@jAVh@Nb@Hb@Vd@V\\r@j@XRt@Zv@JzFIj@Jl@Tp@h@f@n@Pf@Rt@jAzHjAzGR|AL~AF|A?nBiA`\\g@lNMhCOtAWfA]~@k@bA[`@y@t@e@Xs@ZkAXgDReGR_FTgAPiA^cAr@s@r@uAlBqAlBgApA}@r@}@f@wAh@kEv@eC\\_Fx@oLnBkAZg@TgAp@g@b@cEpEqOxP]h@m@jAKd@Kn@Cv@BbDFhBBtCUfGi@~HOxASfA[x@g@v@k@n@}@l@qCjA_Bz@m@^yAzAeC~Ca@\\c@Vg@P_ALmAFiCD@RHNTBN?F|IEd@[lAGb@UfD@l@Hh@HTH|AAr@OrAEp@U~@o@vAg@|@Wv@OjA@Zj@vBf@`Bv@nDjAxCVx@Df@Cj@ZZdCdBbBn@rB`@VJ\\t@vA~H`@tCxAbHb@lB`@|Bn@nB`@~BBbB[rDiApDUGmFaDIQCgCIc@IS[]i@_@SIFd@EXGP]TWLuEzAm@b@k@f@u@\\]kB_@C]OUWSCC]GUCEiChAYgAGOiC\\mDNU?e@KuBkA_@GO@g@XgBbA]@e@CK@eBq@[WSWc@aAcAmD}@oDQ_AUoB[qAiAkDSg@Y]SG_@AcAX_A`@}@n@w@x@c@r@Sv@YzAm@vB[r@u@`AkAhAi@Ny@b@g@d@m@`Ae@p@_AdAyBrB]d@wAlCc@Ge@?SJYd@aA~B]f@k@b@eBd@SBI`@_@dAYd@UXa@R_@DQA_A}@kAa@WAcBT]Ae@ImAYU@k@Xq@f@Q\\K|@Ux@QlA?d@Fj@SCg@Q_@_@Ue@i@eBUYa@UUI{@m@[g@c@u@OMUI]AYJWT[n@S|@OhA[dAYn@YXs@f@i@X}@\\_BPeCNwBBgEe@i@Qy@e@}@k@s@Yo@EyBDeAM]GqJOwAHoCb@oGb@sA?_BUqAYc@O[Q[YY_@{BqDs@wAcC_G_@u@YYmCsB[a@g@eAqAgEkDeI}@gBq@}@{B_Cw@s@e@g@}@iAqCcFq@yAg@}@u@oBeAaDc@cA{@}AwAwBsG}H}@kAeAcB]w@e@{A]cBSuBCkADgDNiET_H?qACm@SyAYcAUi@g@{@{@}@w@k@gHoEcCgA_E{AcEqAeA_@qAq@}@u@mAqA}AyB]m@mFmHw@qAg@iBOuACiBD}@HaAhFiT~CiNNaAFs@BsAI{AQoAY{@Wi@]m@kIaKuB{BkC_CyD_D}OoNiAy@qAk@gEsAeAg@cBuAqFgFmCuCgFeGmFoGu@gAUy@YwCIaB?g@JsDN}D?uAGgAQ}@_@aAU]i@k@eAm@mLoEaCoAiGiDuHgE}@a@_Ck@kAGmBLoM~A{ACkOaEgAc@_Ak@oCgCeAi@aJaDuCcAiAq@m@i@u@u@PeAv@mKh@wGZ{ELmEAwAMkBUyAa@sAsBiGgLe[aE_LSq@Q_AIk@Ae@F{AToBzDgVPoAD_A?cASuFSyBS_AeA}Dk@uCIi@_@gDc@yF?q@@q@Hq@jAuFRu@Ri@dAgBrB_Cd@o@`@u@J]LaAF_D@}APiGAeAKwAeC_PIw@?oABe@Hc@Vw@Vo@bCyDvBeDpI_O`AoBVw@BMBk@A_@Eg@Uw@u@gBmAgCUo@YqAkBsQEo@CiBZ}F`@aHDiAAeAOuAg@iCqB{Hg@wBO{@MqA?m@Fw@|@aDhDiK`AeDLw@D_@?e@Cs@{@mGsBaNeAwGSmAMe@s@eA[[w@c@mQuGw@Qa@Eq@?g@JeAd@}HlEiCpAw@XuARwAAg@E_@Qk@]oB}AwCmCiEiEaDqCwB_BkEyDuEsDkCeCoBuB}A_CqEaHmAkBwCqD}BiC_EiEm@m@y@mAa@y@_DmFuDyFOg@k@sC}@yDiAoGQw@c@mAwDeGcA}Ae@i@QIg@KaAIq@Km@WeBcCmAwAw@cAk@kAGa@Gq@@[B]b@oBt@cEcAuDc@wAmLsc@s@{BqJmWqIoVsIaVcFyNgWws@_DgIg@gBMeAAq@Jo@La@dBaBvG{F|GcGVGZId@?\\FXPX\\Nb@Dr@Gd@Q`@[\\[N]Bk@@o_@sKuA]qEs@kIqBskAu\\eHsBcBa@kAUcL}Aui@kGuBc@aBg@_Bo@qXyMkHgDuEeBc[aKsCcAkBw@eG_DaYuOy\\qRoBuA_RqNwAcA{BiBmDmCkIgGmPaMkAaAyAyAI_@A_@HYxDiIPAPYQXQ@MX"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The "encodedPolyline" object can be decoded and displayed on a map using [Google's interactive polyline decoder utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/polylinedecoder).
I want to display this polyline that shows up when using the decoder utility on my map which is in a vue js project.
How would I go about displaying, or decoding the polyline on my map?
I looked around, and I didn't find an API for the decode utility.
Here is my current vuejs component, just in case:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GMapMap
      :center="center"
      :zoom="13"
      map-type-id="terrain"
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute"
      
    >
    </GMapMap>
  </div>
</template>
  
  <script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      center: { lat: 31.950695, lng: 35.923022 },
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I looked up solutions, and I asked GPT, and checked youtube. I did not have any success finding what I was searching for, and it is not a foreign concept so I just figured I did not know what I was looking for, so I would ask about it on stack overflow so actual people read it and understood what I was looking for. I also tried some Discord communities but I didnt get any responses there.

TL;DR: I want to display a polyline that has many many points on a map. I have an encoded polyline and there is a tool by Google that decodes it, but I don't know how to use the tool in my project.

Comment: I found an answer, I feel dumb but I will leave the question up so if anyone else faces this issue they find an answer. 
So, the string you get from google in the response is an encoded polyline, which is a lossy compression of an array of coordinates. so using an algorithm that was hard for me to find, you can decode that string to get the array of coordinates. the algorithm is available [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-polyline-codec?tab=readme-ov-file). I hope you find this helpful. If there are any questions, ask me and I'll try to answer them :)

Comment: Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77235567/how-to-decode-a-polyline-and-draw-it-on-a-google-map-using-react-google-maps-a) is the link to the question where I found my answer.

Comment: Decoding utility is part of the Geometry library. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry?hl=en#encoding.decodePath

Comment: +1 on the decoding utility MrUpsidown provided. You just have to simply pass down the `encodedPolyline` result you got and use the resulting `LatLng` path to the Vue Google Maps `Polyline` component: https://vue-map.netlify.app/components/polyline.html#add-polyline-to-the-map